# TSQL: INSERT or UPDATE from SELECT result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query where I grab some data from tables, and use the result to insert into a table called finalTable. finalTable.col1 is a pk. However, there are some rows in the finalTable that already exists with the same pk prior to running the below query. I want to change it so that it inserts(if the pk does not exist in finalTable) or updates(if the pk already exist in finalTable).

```
INSERT INTO finalTable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
(
SELECT o.id, 14, 0, 1, 4
FROM Table1 c
INNER JOIN Table2 m ON c.ID = m.ID 
INNER JOIN Table3 o ON m.ID = o.ID 
WHERE c.ID = 40
)
```

One solution I came up with is deleting any relevant rows in finalTable prior to running the above query.

Another solution I came up with is to use "if exists". I would put the select query in the if exists statement, the clause of the if, and the clause of the else. I don't like this solution as I have to put the select query in 3 places, rather than in just 1 place.

```
if exists(...)
begin
  ... -- update
end
else
begin
  ... -- insert
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement for such cases.

```
MERGE finaltable as target
USING (SELECT o.id
       FROM Table1 c
       INNER JOIN Table2 m ON c.ID = m.ID 
       INNER JOIN Table3 o ON m.ID = o.ID 
       WHERE c.ID = 40) as source
ON target.col1=source.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET col2=14,col3=0,col4=1,col5=4
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
VALUES (source.id,14, 0, 1, 4)
```

Comment: Add ; at the end of query, A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).